# Curve on the top/bottom of a div or element

Tags: css

I am looking to achieve as shown:
[image: Curve on top of a div]

I have tried border-radius on a pseudo element but the curve is ugly and smoothly as opposed to ending 'abruptly' with sharp corners - if you know what I mean.

The same div needs the same curve on the bottom, but inverted version of the one in image.
Also, considering an image:
[image: Similar curve on top and bottom]

How would I achieve this in CSS?

Comment: Have a look at clip path http://bennettfeely.com/clippy/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `border-radius` with different values for the vertical radius and the horizontal radius using the [slash syntax](https://www.sitepoint.com/setting-css3-border-radius-with-slash-syntax/):

```css
.picture {
  border-radius: 50%/10%;
}
```

```html
<img class="picture" src="https://static-s.aa-cdn.net/img/ios/608437635/d606ff565c22f64d84e4c2195981c386?v=1">
```

Comment: B.e.a.u.t.i.f.u.l

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this. I have used black background in div to make it more clear. You can remove that black color as per your requirements.

```css
.figure {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: black;
  overflow:hidden;
}
img{
  width:100%;
  border-bottom-left-radius: 100%30px;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100%30px; 
  border-top-left-radius: 100%30px;
  border-top-right-radius: 100%30px; 
}
```

```html
<div class="figure">
<img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/thumb/1/14/Quaidportrait.jpg/220px-Quaidportrait.jpg" />
</div>
```

You can check working CodePen here. https://codepen.io/sajiddesigner/pen/BZOwWa